# MVC Dropdownlist is not validating and give warning

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my class code

```
    public string tempHouseHoldSSNVerification { get; set; }
```

This is my cshtml code

```
   <tr>
                <td width="550"><p class="text-primary">Was an error found for SSN verification?</p></td>
                <td width="20"></td>
                @{ 
                    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
                    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = "-- Select One -- ",
                        Value = null,
                        Selected = true                            
                    });
                    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = "N/A",
                        Value = "N/A"
                    });
                    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = "Yes",
                        Value = "Yes"
                    });
                    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = "No",
                        Value = "No"
                    });
                }

                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.tempHouseHoldSSNVerification, listItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.tempHouseHoldSSNVerification)             
                </td>
   </tr>
```

I want to make sure that the users select one of the three options N/A, Yes, or No, otherwise it will give the users a warning.

Comment: You need to make the property required by adding the  `[Required]` attribute. But you should remove your first `SelectListItem` and instead use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.tempHouseHoldSSNVerification, listItems, "-- Select One --", new { @class = "form-control" })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make `tempHouseHoldSSNVerification` as a Required field.

Example:

```
[Required]
public string tempHouseHoldSSNVerification { get; set; }
```

and your method, check `ModelState` validation

```
public ActionResult YourActionName()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       //do somthing
    }
    return View(); // validation error, so re-display same view
}
```

and also you can use JQuery Validation for client side validation.

hopefully it's help you.